# É possível trabalhar diretamente com os fontes do EntityFramework?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

**É possível trabalhar diretamente com os fontes do *Entity Framework* e poder *"debugar"* por dentro de suas classes e métodos?**

Baixei o zip do código dele contido no **[CodePlex](https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework6)**. Descompactei em uma pasta e em meu projeto adicionei diretamente o projeto:

> ..\EntityFramework\src\EntityFramework\EntityFramework.csproj

A compilação não reporta nenhum erro. Mas ao rodar minha aplicação é exibido a seguinte mensagem de erro:

> Não foi possível carregar arquivo ou assembly 'EntityFramework' ou uma de suas dependências. Não foi possível verificar a assinatura de nome forte. Talvez o assembly tenha sido violado ou assinado com atraso, porém não totalmente assinado com a chave privada correta. (Exceção de HRESULT: 0x80131045)

Digamos que seja por didática, para testar mais a fundo como ele trata algumas tarefas.

**Se é possível e essa mensagem de erro é por conta de algo errado que fiz ou algo que deixei de fazer, o que devo então fazer e como preparar minha aplicação para trabalhar diretamente com os fontes do *Entity Framework*?**

**Se é possível e vocês fazem isso comumente, então como posso organizar meu projeto de forma mais simples para trabalhar com ele diretamente pelos fontes?**

---

## EDIÇÃO

Conforme indicação do @Cigano, estou tentando com os fontes repositório no Github:

> https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework

Porém, estou recebendo várias mensagens de erro:

> Package references not found. Run 'build initialize' before opening solution for first time.

**O que ele está me pedindo? Como fazer?**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Usando Nightly Builds

É possível trabalhar também com os lançamentos diários de versão feitos pela Micosoft, mas que são empacotados e não sei se as DLLs desses pacotes possuem informações de Debug. De qualquer forma, creio que seja possível misturar este método com o método mais abaixo.

Utilize o seguinte link para fazer o passo a passo da configuração do EF7 na sua aplicação usando pacotes noturnos: https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Using-EF7-in-Traditional-.NET-Applications

## Roteiro para instalar e usar o Entity Framework pelos fontes

O que devo ensinar aqui é para compilar o Entity Framework 7, que na data desta resposta é a edição beta fornecida no GitHub.

### 1. Baixe os fontes

Neste passo suponho que você tem pelo menos uma conta do GitHub e tem noções de como usá-lo.

Utilizando o [GitHub for Windows](https://windows.github.com/), clone em sua máquina o seguinte repositório:

> https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework

### 2. Inicialize sua cópia

Vá na raiz do diretório `EntityFramework` baixado pelo seu GitHub, abra nele um prompt de comando (no Windows Explorer, segure <kbd>Shift</kbd> e clique com o botão direito no diretório, depois escolha a opção <kbd>Open Command Window Here</kbd>, ou em português, <kbd>Abrir prompt de comando aqui</kbd> ), e digite:

```
build initialize
```

Será invocado o NuGet e as dependências do projeto serão instaladas automaticamente. A janela ficará mais ou menos assim:

[image: Entity Framework 1]

## 3. Abra e compile o projeto

O projeto abre no [Visual Studio 2013](http://www.visualstudio.com/pt-br/downloads) com o [Update 2](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=390521). Aberto o projeto, basta compilar o projeto `EntityFramework.SqlServer`:

[image: Compilando o Entity Framework]

## 4. Substitua as DLLs dos Packages

Para o teste, adicionei todos os arquivos compilados que estavam dentro de `src/EntityFramework.SqlServer/bin/Debug` dentro do diretório `packages/EntityFramework-<versão>/lib/net45`. Possivelmente você precisará retirar as referências antigas no projeto antes de substituir esses arquivos.

Comment: Abra o Package Manager Console e digite `build initialize`.

Comment: @TiagoSilva Na verdade era este o comando. Eu ainda não pude realizar o procedimento todo. Fico te devendo pra uma oportunidade em que eu esteja mais tranquilo.

Answer (score 4):

O *Entity Framework* contido no ***GitHub*** é a versão 7, enquanto que o instalado nas aplicações via ***NuGet*** é a versão 6.1, conforme testado no VS 2013, ainda é do  ***CodePlex***.

Conforme informações na Wiki do EF 7, no GitHub:

> - Data Annotations are not yet supported for configuring a model.
> - The Fluent API only has very basic functionality implemented so far. For many modelling concerns (such as defining relationships between entities) you need to manipulate the underlying object model directly.

Atritubos ainda não são suportados e a Fluent API está em uma versão muito básica.

Em meus testes, adicionando referência aos projetos ***EntityFramework***, ***EntityFramework.SqlServer*** e ***Migrate*** já foi possível compilar e executar o projeto sem erros.
Consegui fazer o debug pelos métodos.

**Observação**: Nestes testes que fiz ainda não fiz cópia das pastas desses projetos para dentro do meu, adicionei os projetos à minha solução buscando eles diretamente da pasta onde descompactei os fontes do *Entity Framework*.

Já que é para uma questão didática e para testar mais a fundo como o EF está trabalhando com meu modelo, a versão contida no NuGet, no momento, me é mais interessante.